# Security considerations for managing internal network from an external website

Tags: network, wifi, router

With my previous network setups, I managed my network by connecting to the internal IP address of my router (e.g. 192.168.1.1).

I recently switched to google fiber and installed their "fiber box" (a combined router/modem, as I understand it) in place of my old modem and router. Connecting directly to the router's IP adress now presents a very minimal page that directs me to https://fiber.google.com/myfiber/ to manage my internal network settings. It is this external page that allows me to do things like assign static IP addresses and modify WiFi settings.

Is this something I should be concerned about, or is it just as secure as managing network settings "internally"? If there are risks, how can I mitigate them?

Answer (score 1):

You are basically managing your network through Google. You define settings on Google's account page, and on boot the router pulls settings from them. This allows for example easy migration to a new/replacement router, as it just pulls the latest configuration on boot.

Because we're talking about Google I assume they've done their homework as far as securing the data in transit between your computer and their systems, and your router. I would expect everything to happen over HTTPS, so it is secure in transit.

Data storage on their systems should be secure as well, but if it isn't then you've got much bigger problems than your router configuration being accessible - your entire Google account would be at risk, including GMail, etc. So personally assuming you're fine with Google controlling your router and having access to your network, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Enable 2FA (2 factor authentication), and print some rescue codes.

Basically, do what you can to secure your Google account, and don't worry about the box in specific.

Since you have network access, you have to assume there is some mechanism (or several) to ensure Google is providing services that are being paid for (this is something most ISPs put a fairly remarkable amount of effort into).

So your connectivity depends on Google feeling confident enough to provide paying services - which includes allowing you to manage your local network

If you are *seriously* worried about this, buy yourself a small box with a couple of NICs to act as a firewall you control.